# Captar datos de un bucle con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un código que me genera un bucle, el cual capta toda la información en etiquetas Text
, el problema nace cuando intento captar un dato en específico con JQuery, como lo podría ser un id de entre los 5 que tengo almacenados en la base de datos, ya que al momento de imprimir el id en una alerta solo me aparece el primero que fue creado en el ciclo y no el que fue seleccionado en el JSP.

```
                while (iter.hasNext()) { 
        %>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 m-l-r-auto">
            <div class="blo3 flex-w flex-col-l-sm m-b-30" id="Agregar_a_la_compra">

                <input type="text" id="id" value="<%=pedidos.getId()%>">

                <div class="text-blo3 size21 flex-col-l-m">
```

Como se puede ver lo que se imprime en pantalla son los id de la base de datos como serian (1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5) pero mi interés es que cuando el usuario seleccione el id 3, aparezca el id 3 en un alert , para esto realice el siguiente código en JQuery.

```
$(function () {
$("#Agregar_a_la_compra button , a").click(function () {
    alert ($('#id_reseta').val());
}); });
```

Pero como ya dije anteriormente el único valor que me aparece es 1 y no el 3 que es el que seleccione.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al iterar estás generando el id="Agregar_a_la_compra" muchas veces, al ser un id debería ser unico dentro del DOM.
Jquery toma el primer id que encuentra dentro de los elementos del html.
Lo dejaría así:

```
<div class="blo3 flex-w flex-col-l-sm m-b-30" data-id="<%=pedidos.getId()%>" class="Agregar_a_la_compra">
```

Y el código JS así:

```
$(function () {
   $(".Agregar_a_la_compra").on('click',function () {
       alert ($(this).attr('data-id'));
   }); 
});
```

De esta manera colocas a "Agregar_a_la_compra" como una clase, puedes agregarla múltiple veces dentro del loop y luego desde el js haces referencia al attr data-id.
Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no soluciono completamente mi problema pero fue una excelente guía para resolverlo.